Query stays hanging indefinitely on MariaDB 10.6
I'm using CiviCRM v5.76.1 on MariaDB 10.6.18 (Ubuntu 22.04).
I created a complex search with SearchKit looking in the table civicrm_line_item (450000 rows)  and the query stays hanging indefinitely (actually the result came back after almost 2 hours of execution).
This is the generated SQL query:
SELECT
  `a`.`id` AS `id`,
  `a`.`sort_name` AS `sort_name`,
  MAX(`Contact_Membership_contact_id_01`.`end_date`) AS `MAX_Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_end_date`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT `Contact_Membership_contact_id_01`.`membership_type_id` SEPARATOR ""
  ) AS `GROUP_CONCAT_Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_membership_type_id_label`,
  `Associazione_2`.`display_name` AS `chapter_reference.Associazione.display_name`,
  SUM(`contribution_id_3`.`total_amount`) AS `SUM_Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_Membership_LineItem_entity_id_01_contribution_id_total_amount`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT `Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_Membership_LineItem_entity_id_01`.`entity_table` SEPARATOR ""
  ) AS `GROUP_CONCAT_Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_Membership_LineItem_entity_id_01_entity_table_label`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT `Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_Membership_LineItem_entity_id_01`.`price_field_value_id` SEPARATOR ""
  ) AS `GROUP_CONCAT_Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_Membership_LineItem_entity_id_01_price_field_value_id_label`,
  MAX(`Anno_di_riferimento_4`.`anno_43`) AS `MAX_Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_Membership_LineItem_entity_id_01_LineItem_Contribution_contribution_id_01_Anno_di_riferimento_Anno`,
  `email_primary_5`.`email` AS `email_primary.email`,
  `phone_primary_6`.`phone` AS `phone_primary.phone`,
  `address_primary_7`.`postal_code` AS `address_primary.postal_code`,
  `address_primary_7`.`street_address` AS `address_primary.street_address`,
  `address_primary_7`.`city` AS `address_primary.city`
FROM
  civicrm_contact a
  INNER JOIN (
    `civicrm_membership` `Contact_Membership_contact_id_01`
  ) ON `a`.`id` = `Contact_Membership_contact_id_01`.`contact_id`
  AND `Contact_Membership_contact_id_01`.`status_id` IN ("4", "5", "6")
  LEFT JOIN (
    `civicrm_membership` `Contact_Membership_contact_id_02`
  ) ON `a`.`id` = `Contact_Membership_contact_id_02`.`contact_id`
  AND `Contact_Membership_contact_id_02`.`status_id` IN ("1", "2")
  LEFT JOIN `civicrm_value_associazione_32` `chapter_reference_1` ON `a`.`id` = `chapter_reference_1`.`entity_id`
  LEFT JOIN (
    `civicrm_contact` `Contact_Contact_Associazione_01`
  ) ON `chapter_reference_1`.`associazione_67` = `Contact_Contact_Associazione_01`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN (
    `civicrm_line_item` `Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_Membership_LineItem_entity_id_01`
  ) ON `Contact_Membership_contact_id_01`.`id` = `Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_Membership_LineItem_entity_id_01`.`entity_id`
  AND `Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_Membership_LineItem_entity_id_01`.`entity_table` = "civicrm_membership"
  LEFT JOIN (
    `civicrm_contribution` `Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_Membership_LineItem_entity_id_01_LineItem_Contribution_contribution_id_01`
  ) ON `Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_Membership_LineItem_entity_id_01`.`contribution_id` = `Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_Membership_LineItem_entity_id_01_LineItem_Contribution_contribution_id_01`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `civicrm_contact` `Associazione_2` ON `chapter_reference_1`.`associazione_67` = `Associazione_2`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `civicrm_contribution` `contribution_id_3` ON `Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_Membership_LineItem_entity_id_01`.`contribution_id` = `contribution_id_3`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `civicrm_value_anno_di_rifer_22` `Anno_di_riferimento_4` ON `Contact_Membership_contact_id_01_Membership_LineItem_entity_id_01_LineItem_Contribution_contribution_id_01`.`id` = `Anno_di_riferimento_4`.`entity_id`
  LEFT JOIN `civicrm_email` `email_primary_5` ON `a`.`id` = `email_primary_5`.`contact_id`
  AND `email_primary_5`.`is_primary` = 1
  LEFT JOIN `civicrm_phone` `phone_primary_6` ON `a`.`id` = `phone_primary_6`.`contact_id`
  AND `phone_primary_6`.`is_primary` = 1
  LEFT JOIN `civicrm_address` `address_primary_7` ON `a`.`id` = `address_primary_7`.`contact_id`
  AND `address_primary_7`.`is_primary` = 1
WHERE
  (`a`.`is_deleted` = "0")
  AND (`Contact_Membership_contact_id_02`.`id` IS NULL)
GROUP BY
  `a`.`id`,
  `chapter_reference_1`.`associazione_67`
ORDER BY
  `a`.`sort_name` ASC


The MariaDB innodb_buffer_pool_size variable is set to 12G.
This problem started happening to me recently after I upgraded to version 5.76.1, but I don't think it depends on that, maybe on the MariaDB version instead (I was using 10.3 a while ago).
I tried to investigate (with EXPLAIN) and I think the problem is in the table civicrm_line_item: the join in that table does not use any indexes. So I add this index:
ALTER TABLE `civicrm_line_item` 
ADD INDEX(`entity_table`, `entity_id`)

and now the query works in a reasonable time.
Does anyone know of any problems with MariaDB 10.6?
Do you think a PR could be done to add indexes on entity_table + entity_id fields? Why has this not been done so far?
